# Idiomatic macros for malloc in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, malloc

## Background

I am learning low-level dev after working with `C++` for high level projects for a decent stretch. Currently bumbling about typical `C` patterns and stumbling across bits of the linux kernel and old emails.

## Question

Are there a set of *commonly used/idiomatic* macros, or generic functions which reduce repetition or reduce mistakes in memory allocation?

Something I see a lot in my code is long multiplication statements inside of malloc which I see as tedious, and a ripe place for problems.
Example:

```c
struct my_struct {
    size_t size;
    char* memory;
}

struct my_struct* my_struct_new(size_t size) {
    struct my_struct* ms = malloc(sizeof *ms)
    
    ms->size = size;
    ms->memory = malloc(size * sizeof *ms->memory);

    return ms;
}
```

---

I'm trying to avoid creating an XY problem through giving my bad tries here.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Nope. We are writing like this :) some parentheses might help though

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: nope.

Comment: @HunterKoler I'd say that you should keep writing like that. I can understand it - and that's a good thing. Add error checking and you'll be home!

Comment: `struct my_struct *my_struct_new(size_t size) {` <<-- to avoid confusion, I would prefer the name `count` for the parameter name, not `size`.

Comment: I prefer `calloc()` over `malloc()` when allocating arrays, fwiw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there a set of commonly used/idiomatic macros, or generic functions which reduce repetition or reduce mistakes in memory allocation?

Not really, [@John Bode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642646/2410359) has it mostly covered.

Make a allocator function for `struct my_struct` - very idiomatic in C.

Minor weakness in the implementation is the lack of checking for out-of-memory -  something expected with robust code.

```
struct my_struct* my_struct_new(size_t size) {
    struct my_struct *ms = malloc(sizeof *ms)
    if (ms) {
      ms->size = size;
      ms->memory = malloc(size * sizeof *ms->memory);
      if (ms->memory == NULL) {
        free(ms);
        ms = NULL;
      }
    }
    return ms;
}
```

Also research [Flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

```
struct my_struct_fma {
    size_t size;
    char memory[];
}

struct my_struct_fma *my_struct_new_fma(size_t size) {
    struct my_struct_fma *ms = malloc(sizeof *ms + sizeof *ms->memory * size);
    if (ms) {
      ms->size = size;
      }
    }
    return ms;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that's pretty much the idiomatic way to allocate memory in C.  The `*alloc` functions don't know or care about types, they only care about how many bytes you want.  The best way to get that number (for things other than strings or byte buffers, anyway) is to multiply the size of the target (`sizeof *ms->memory`) by the number of elements you want (`size)`.  Otherwise you can use `calloc` which passes those things as separate arguments, but `calloc` will zero-initialize the memory, which may or may not be what you want.

You can and should abstract out complex allocations into their own functions (as this snippet does).  but as far as any existing convenience macros - not really.

Comment: Just for OP's benefit, one subtle advantage of `calloc` is that it will fail safely if the multiplication overflows, whereas `malloc(n * sizeof(*p))` may silently allocate too little.

Comment: @nate: not necessarily. Many C library implementations don't bother testing for overflow.

Comment: To correct myself, it's not actually overflow in the terms of standard C, because the arguments to calloc have an unsigned type. It's modular arithmetic. But either way, the result is less memory than requested.

Comment: @rici "Many C library implementations don't bother testing for overflow." --> Hmmm, sounds  non-compliant.  Have a current sample library in mind?   "The calloc function allocates space for an array of `nmemb` objects, each of whose size is `size`. The space is initialized to all bits zero" has no exception for `size_t` math overflow nor does spec specify the multiplication is limited to `size_t` math.    `calloc(a,b)`  can allocate more than `SIZE_MAX` on systems that support it.

Comment: *but `calloc` will zero-initialize the memory, which may or may not be what you want*  I tend to like the clearing of memory - it makes my mistakes show up faster.  "What a minute, that pointer isn't supposed to be `NULL` here..."

Comment: @chux: i didn't have a current implementation in mind, no. Just a vivid memory of having been burnt. I think there are fewer of these than there used to be but here's one which seems current: https://github.com/rhempel/umm_malloc/blob/master/src/umm_malloc.c#L706. i agree that the behaviour is probably non-compliant. But that doesn't make it ignorable if it happens.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I agree that the standard read literally seems to require overflow / wraparound checking, but I'm a little surprised they didn't include a footnote to make this explicit.  It does seem like something an implementor could easily overlook.